# HTML Tag Showing in View of Rails App when Using Internet Explorer

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer

When I view my Rails (3.1) app in Internet Explorer, for some reason it sometimes shows bits of html tags at the end of my page, but it doesn't do this in Chrome or Firefox.  In particular, it shows part of the  tag - never the full tag, but part - like `</h` or `</htm` - in the view as text (at the bottom of the page).

In my layout template, I do have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title><%= title %></title>

     <% if params[:controller] == 'pages' %>
       <%= stylesheet_link_tag "static_pages", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" %>
     <%  elsif %>
       <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" %>  
     <% end %>

     <%= javascript_include_tag "https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js", "admin.js" %>

     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        //jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
                "sSortAsc": "header headerSortDown",
                "sSortDesc": "header headerSortUp",
                "sSortable": "header"
            } );

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#datatable').dataTable( {
                    "sDom": "<'row'<'span5'l><'span8'f>r>t<'row'<'span4'i><'span8'p>>",
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
                     } );
            } );
      </script>

      <%= yield :javascript%>
      <%= yield :script%>

   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```

When I look at the html source code generated for the view, I notice that the Chrome/Firefox the source concludes with `</body>` and not `</html>` (or any partial code like IE).

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: did you try to paste the parts of your tag that show up?  if so, it didn't come through.

Comment: I didn't realize that, thanks.  I added it now, </h or </htm

Comment: does it do this randomly, or for specific pages?

Comment: it happens for specific pages

Comment: there must be some invalid html in those specific pages.  Are you able to paste the html from one of them?  you could use something like pastie.org

Comment: I created a gist of the html: https://gist.github.com/2727283 .  However, the issue has something to do with Rails because as you can see the </html> tag did not complete so of course in this example, as you'd expect it ends with the text </htm.  What I don't understand is why Rails only generated part of the tag, as this happens in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

An empty Head tag will not be recognized as well formed (closed ) unless it contains a mandatory child 
( as defined in the DTD of the doctype 'Transitional' you are using. )

Give it a title

```
 <head>
  <title>A Title</title>
 </head>
```

I think this is mandatory for all doctypes ( but don't quote me on that ) - but mute point too - every web page should have a title.

Update: Says title is present, still sounds like a "well formed" issue though ..

1) Run, **view source** and copy all the code into notepad/simular and save that as test.html ( this will highlight any chars that are not correct like ( " ) etc ..

2) Upload your test.html into the w3c validator service [w3c Validator service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload)
That should give some good clues

hope that cracs it

Comment: oh - the head tag isn't empty, i just didn't paste it in.  I'll paste it in, sorry about that

Comment: ok, I have updated the answer with a couple of things to check